# How to detect whether my Phonegap Activity is already running or not?

Tags: android, cordova, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I have developed a android application using phonegap. I have registered certain recievers which get invoked as per my needs. Now the issue which i am facing is that if my application is already open then the reciever is opening the activity again. It happens because i coded in such a way. But suppose if my application was close then there is no issue.

So i think so i need to check whether the activity is open and then open it accordingly. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post contains set of solution which might help you decide which one is suitable for you requirement.

[Checking if an Android application is running in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667022/android-is-application-running-in-background)